# What is the difference between *.volt and *.phtml files in PhalconPHP?

Tags: view, php, phalcon, difference, volt

Iin the sample projects of Phalcon, in the views directory we have some files with **volt** suffix and **phtml** suffix. What is the difference between this two suffix? When we must use **Volt** and when we must use **phtml** ?! please explain for me...

Answer (score 9, accepted):

.volt extension is used when the template engine set up in the application is Volt (http://docs.phalconphp.com/en/latest/reference/volt.html), .phtml is used when the template engine is PHP itself (http://docs.phalconphp.com/en/latest/reference/views.html#template-engines)